# To receive input from user using char array and to display to the user element by element using array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to write a program which takes in a `String` as `char[]` and display the `char[]` using a for-loop to print out `char` after `char`.

During compilation shows an error that the **char cannot be converted to char[]**

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayArray{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int i;
       System.out.println("Please insert your name");
       char name[] = input.next().charAt(0);

       for(i=0; i < name.length; i++){
         System.out.println(name[i]);
       }

  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix on this code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `charAt` returns a single char and you're trying to assign it to char array. Maybe read whole line as string, convert it to an array, assign to `name[]` and the print?

Comment: so should I remove the `charAt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
char name[] = input.next().charAt(0);
```

use something like

```
 String nameStr = scanner.next();
 char[] name = nameStr.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Or `char[] name = nameStr.toCharArray();`

Comment: or going with that or `char[] name = nameStr.split("");` only `toCharArray` works.